# Why do I get "generic parameters may not be used in const operations" error when compiling dependencies?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to compile [the sample code](https://docs.rs/docx/latest/docx/) from the docx crate:

```toml
# Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
docx = "1.1.2"
```

```
//! main.rs
use docx::document::Paragraph;
use docx::DocxFile;

fn main() {
    let docx = DocxFile::from_file("origin.docx").unwrap();
    let mut docx = docx.parse().unwrap();

    let para = Paragraph::default().push_text("Lorem Ipsum");
    docx.document.push(para);

    docx.write_file("origin_appended.docx").unwrap();
}
```

This is the full error I'm getting:

```
   Compiling bzip2-sys v0.1.11+1.0.8
   Compiling jetscii v0.4.4
   Compiling quote v1.0.21
   Compiling time v0.1.44
error: generic parameters may not be used in const operations
   --> /home/thwart/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/jetscii-0.4.4/src/simd.rs:109:13
    |
109 |             T::CONTROL_BYTE,
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot perform const operation using `T`
    |
    = note: type parameters may not be used in const expressions

error: generic parameters may not be used in const operations
   --> /home/thwart/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/jetscii-0.4.4/src/simd.rs:148:13
    |
148 |             T::CONTROL_BYTE,
    |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot perform const operation using `T`
    |
    = note: type parameters may not be used in const expressions

error: could not compile `jetscii` due to 2 previous errors
```

Why is Rust compiling jetscii? How do I fix this error?

Comment: What version of Rust are you on?

Comment: rustc -V = 1.62.1

Comment: @PitaJ That's a horribly old version of `jetscii`. Could be that `docx` should update to a new version. Although this is weird to me in general, because the Rust compiler should not break code that once compiled.

Comment: So it seems like the problem is with the 'docx' crate & not the sample code above.  I added docx as a dependency to my hello-world project and got the same error.

Comment: @ed_is_my_name Yah, I figured. The compiler error is in the compilation of the `docx` crate, not your code.

Comment: https://github.com/PoiScript/docx-rs/issues/51

Comment: Thanks for your time.  Perhaps, I should try a different docx parser?

Comment: The docx-rs issue linked above indicates that rustc version 1.63.0 should compile successfully?

Comment: @effect Cannot confirm, it fails for me on 1.63.0. I suspect it's more of an architecture thing whether or not it compiles. `jetscii` is highly machine dependent and even has a custom `build.rs` that dynamically generates machine-dependent code.

Comment: I reported directly to `jetscii`: https://github.com/shepmaster/jetscii/issues/56

Comment: FYI the author of jetscii has responded to the issue @Finomnis created. Long story short, this is one of the very few examples where a change to the Rust compiler ended up breaking existing Rust code.

Comment: @Finomnis, would you like to take credit and summarize everything into an answer?

Comment: @effect not really, feel free to take over

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by an unfortunate combination of a slightly-incompatible Rust update and old crates. The docx library depends on jetscii via this dependency tree:

```
docx v1.1.2
└── strong-xml v0.5.0
    └── jetscii v0.4.4
```

You can view [jetscii issue #56](https://github.com/shepmaster/jetscii/issues/56), [jetscii pull request #39](https://github.com/shepmaster/jetscii/pull/39), and [rust-lang/stdarch issue #248](https://github.com/rust-lang/stdarch/issues/248) for more info, but the basic summary is (courtesy of shepmaster):

> TL;DR, older versions of Rust exposed the SIMD intrinsics in one way, that was changed, and a small number of crates (such as Jetscii) were affected.

The jetscii and strong-xml have long since been updated to accommodate this change but docx has not (no updates in over two years).

To workaround this issue your options are limited:

- use Rust version 1.53
- update docx with newer dependencies yourself
- change libraries (consider [docx-rs](https://crates.io/crates/docx-rs) or [docx-rust](https://crates.io/crates/docx-rust))