# Using generic parameters in const operations

Tags: generics, rust, constants

Edit: Those seeking answers should definitely check out the [Rust forum post](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/using-generic-parameters-in-const-operations/96651).

I'm defining a struct that will hold the results obtained by a [Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter). For my research simulations, I know how much storage I need at compile time, which means I can use const generics to statically allocate arrays. Unfortunately, I am unable to perform const operations on the generic parameters, which means that the following won't compile:

```
pub struct FilterStorage<const N: usize, const P: usize, const COUNT: usize> {
  mx_prior: [[f64; N]; COUNT],
  mx_post:  [[f64; N]; COUNT],
  ex_prior: [[f64; N]; COUNT],
  ex_post:  [[f64; N]; COUNT],
  sx_prior: [[f64; N]; COUNT],
  sx_post:  [[f64; N]; COUNT],
  mx: [[f64; N]; 2 * COUNT],
  ex: [[f64; N]; 2 * COUNT],
  sx: [[f64; N]; 2 * COUNT],
  
  ez: [[f64; P]; COUNT],
  sz: [[f64; P]; COUNT],
}
```

I took a look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73722833/why-do-i-get-generic-parameters-may-not-be-used-in-const-operations-error-when), [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/shepmaster/jetscii/issues/56), [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/shepmaster/jetscii/pull/39), and [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/stdarch/issues/248), but to be honest I don't entirely understand what's being discussed or what it means for how I should proceed. It seems that operations on const generics used to be allowed, but the feature was killed in the pursuit of faster compile times and/or smaller libraries. (I may be misunderstanding, though!)

[This forum post](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/operations-on-const-generic-parameters-as-a-generic-parameter/78865) and [this forum post](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-calculate-2nd-const-parameter-in-function-with-single-const-generic-parameter/62259) are related, but do not seem to answer my question.

I suppose that I could refactor the `mx`, `ex`, and `sx` members out of the struct, since they're really only populated for plotting purposes. On the other hand, that seems like needless fragmentation of data structure.

Is there a workaround? Is this a planned feature? Is it worth figuring out where to put and how to name another struct to store this extremely closely related data?

If you prefer to answer on the Rust forums, see [this post](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/using-generic-parameters-in-const-operations/96651).

Comment: The relevant Rust language feature would be [`generic_const_exprs`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/76560) to allow `2 * COUNT` to work. Your first few links are red herrings.

Comment: @kmdreko Thanks for letting me know about the red herrings! Are you suggesting that I add `#![feature(generic_const_exprs)]` to my crate root and switch to an unstable release channel?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that, unless this is a hobby project. `generic_const_exprs` is a _very_ unstable feature. It is better you avoid it.